# Saving a generic python object externally

Tags: python, object

I moved over from matlab to python about a year ago and am still getting used to the differences. In matlab you could save a structure (the slightly less nice equivalent of an object from a generic class) to an external file. As a result - if you were working with something that generated structures that you didn't understand, you could save them to a file and then compare them.

This file would look something like

```
structure 1
property1: value or values of property 1
property2: value or values of property 2
property3: value or values of property 3

structure 2
property1: value or values of property 1
property2: value or values of property 2
property3: value or values of property 3

structure 3
property1: value or values of property 1
property2: value or values of property 2
property3: value or values of property 3
```

and so on.

Is ther a python way of doing this? Right now i just care about printing them externally - so i can read and compare them. Matlab lets you read them back in, and i don't need that kind of functionality in this case.

Comment: You could simply pickle the object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are looking for? What is a ``structure`` in your case? You can always ``print`` builtin types, and define representations for any data structure. However, probably the most pythonic way of comparing data is not to dump it to a file, but to compare it in the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is ther a python way of doing this? Right now i just care about printing them externally - so i can read and compare them. Matlab lets you read them back in, and i don't need that kind of functionality in this case.

There is no really generic *and* readable serialisation scheme.

`pickle` works with everything but it's *bad*, it's unreadable (in fact it's very much specified as *not human-readable*, and even version 0 is at best to be qualified as "textual") and it's very unsafe.

`json` can be pretty readable, but it won't work out of the box with most types (though it will work with simple structures of builtin types e.g. if you're just creating lists and dicts it's fine).

You could use [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) or [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html), they make structures printable by default. They use the standard "repr" of

```
TypeName(field1=value1, field2=value2, ...)
```

which is somewhat less conducive to easy comparisons via most standard textual diffs, but both provide an `asdict` function which converts instances to dicts, which you can then easily serialise as JSON (with linebreaks and indentation) or some other generic scheme.

Comment: Calling ``pickle`` "very unsafe" seems quite odd. It allows for executable code, which is a problem for data *from untrusted sources*. In trusted environments, it is *the* default serialisation and deserialisation solution for arbitrary objects. Simply storing and loading ones own data via ``pickle`` is *not* unsafe in the slightest.

Comment: "Calling pickle "very unsafe" seems quite odd. It allows for executable code" yes, that would make it unsafe, it's easy to assume it's just a data descriptor. "it is the default serialisation and deserialisation solution for arbitrary objects" no it's not, and really should not be the default *anything* since it's far from merely a serialisation and deserialisation format. "Simply storing and loading ones own data via pickle is not unsafe in the slightest." in the same way it's possible to use a grenade safely, it's possible to use pickle safely. That doesn't make pickle safe.